# How to make normal command `ls` and the wildcard `*` in Zsh

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, zsh

Let's consider the interaction with Zsh on a Mac:

```
 % ls |grep gradle
gradle@7
 % ls gradle*
INSTALL_RECEIPT.json    LICENSE                 NOTICE                  README                  bin                     libexec
```

According to [every description](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/learning-unix-for/0596006179/ch04s02.html) of the functionality of the `*` wildcard, the output of second invocation of `ls` should be same as the first.  Yet, it lists the contents of the folder. Why is that? How can I fix it so that `*` behaves normally?

Obviously, in addition to Googling it (please don't suggest that I Google the answer), I tried reading `man ls` but that's completely unwieldy.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted.  File globbing isn’t a well understood concept.

Comment: @allan Globbing isn’t the issue here. But the downvote nevertheless seems strange.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The glob is expanded by the shell and the resulting arguments passed to `ls` as if you had written them out in full.

1. `gradle*` matches once, on `gradle@7`.
2. `ls gradle@7` is run.

Since `gradle@7` is a directory, `ls` lists the contents. This is documented behaviour of `ls`:

> For each operand that names a file of a type other than directory, ls displays its name […].
> For each operand that names a file of type directory, ls displays the names of files contained within that directory […].

*source: ls man page*

The examples on your link use files, hence the files themselves are printed.

`ls` has an option to print the directory itself rather than its contents.

> `-d` Directories are listed as plain files (not searched recursively).

Comment: thank you.  Exactly what I was looking for.